# How to make Wordpress-like templates?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building my site without CMS and I want for my articles to chose from several templates that I'll build later.

But I don't see how to do this.

I mean, let's say that I have *template01.php*, *template02.php*. How can I retrieve these templates?

The only way I found is to put all the templates in my *index.php* (in the */articles/* folder which is the equivalent of *single.php* in WP) and make conditions like these:

```
if($template==01) {
    TEMPLATE 01
} elseif($template==02) {
    TEMPLATE 02
}
...
```

Do you have an idea how to use this with separate files?

What I don't understand is : if I go to *www.mysite.com/article/a-very-cool-article/*, how it will show the article with the second template instead of the first template?

I hope that I was understandable...

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely activating the variable on the individual page will activate your template.

I.e. adding the line;

```
var $template == 01
```

or

```
var $template == 02
```

to the articles you wish to use template 1 or 2 would return whatever conditions you have stipulated in your IF statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that but how to do this with separate files? Because this solutions is involving a lot of files if there is a lot of templates.

Comment: @cyclone200
That's a whole load of coding and explanation.. You'd need to use if statements a starter would be 

`if(template == 01){
    // Do something
} else if (template == 02{
    // Do something else
}   //... etc etc`

Why have you decided not to use a cms? If you're including loads of articles/posts etc your life would be so much easier to use a CMS..

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Goddak. Well, a CMS loads a lot of useless things and it's more interesting to build its own "CMS"..